# openpyxl: ValueError: dtype: int64 to Excel

Tags: excel, merge, openpyxl

I am combining two .csv file and writing a new .xlsx file.

The code goes like this:

```
ODEMPTY = pandas.read_csv('OD_Empty_unduplicated.csv')
ODNEW = pandas.read_csv('OD_Out.csv')

ODNEW = ODNEW.append(ODEMPTY)

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('cm2011.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for i in range(len(ODNEW)):
   sheet['A'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['comm'][i] # start writing on A1 not A0
   sheet['B'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['ONode'][i]
   sheet['C'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['DNode'][i]
   sheet['D'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['quantity'][i]
   sheet['E'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['startRR'][i]
```

Error: ValueError: dtype: int64 to Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently trying to write multiple `pd.Series` to cells. To get just one value you'd have to use `.iloc`, e.g.:

```
for i in range(len(ODNEW)):
   sheet['A'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['comm'].iloc[i] # start writing on A1 not A0
   sheet['B'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['ONode'].iloc[i]
   sheet['C'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['DNode'].iloc[i]
   sheet['D'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['quantity'].iloc[i]
   sheet['E'+ str(i+1)].value = ODNEW['startRR'].iloc[i]
```

But you can iterate over the table directly:

```
for i,j in ODNEW.iterrows():
   sheet['A'+ str(i+1)].value = j['ONode']
   sheet['C'+ str(i+1)].value = j['DNode']
   sheet['D'+ str(i+1)].value = j['quantity']
   sheet['E'+ str(i+1)].value = j['startRR']
```

Otherwise look at the utility function provided here: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/pandas.html

Comment: That worked!! But, I still don't understand why this code stopped working. It was working perfectly before.